# Elasticsearch special conditions query

Tags: elasticsearch, conditional-statements, elasticsearch-query

i have conditions in my elasticsearch documents, for example:

```
{
...
    "conditions": [
      {
        "required": ["a"],
        "prohibited": ["f"]
      },
      {
        "required": ["a", "b"],
        "prohibited": ["c", "d"]
      }
    ]
}
```

And a have a dataset, for example `["a", "b", "f"]` (a `true` example, because second condition matches)

Now I want to write a Elasticsearch-Query that returns all documents to which the conditions apply to my dataset. The tricky part which i am hanging on is not to loose the single conditions relations. All entries in `required` have to match **in combindation** and with `prohibited` it's the same.

Hope there is a es-specialist who can give me an approach what the best way is to solve this challenge. At the moment i think on a Script-Query or different structure of these conditions in our documents. But maybe there is a way (which i don't see) to formulate this as normal ES-Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries and frustration i decided to solve my problem with a painless script. It's not perfect from a performance point of view but it works.